# How do I add new dimensions to a fact table without having to rebuild the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, data-warehouse

I'm new to data warehousing so apologies if this is super basic, but I'm curious about this concept.

Example: say I have a table that stores aggregated analytics for a website, (e.g. the total pageviews for a url on a given date).

**dbo.PageFacts**

| Date | Url_Id | Page_Views |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 280 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | 50 |
| 2020-01-02 | 3 | 10 |

Now let's say I'm tasked with adding a new "Device_Id" column to this table (foreign keyed to its own dimension table), and now the table is split out like this...

| Date | Url_Id | Device_Id | Page_Views |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 101 | 180 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 102 | 100 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | 101 | 50 |
| 2020-01-02 | 3 | 101 | 10 |

How do most people go about doing this for a fact table with millions of records? I'm assuming you don't want to rebuild it every time new dimensions are added in like, especially when it requires updating the aggregated value.

I was thinking of creating a surrogate key on the fact table and then creating a separate dimension table with percent breakdowns (e.g. 0.75, 0.25, etc) and then just building a VIEW that joins them together and computes the new values? Something like this...

```sql
CREATE TABLE PageFacts (
    PageSurKey INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Date DATE,
    Url_Id INT,
    Page_Views INT
);
CREATE TABLE Device_Pct (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    PageSurKey INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PageFacts(PageSurKey),
    Device_Id INT,
    Percentage FLOAT
);


CREATE VIEW Device_PageFacts AS
SELECT
    pf.Date,
    pf.Url_Id,
    d.Device_Id,
    SUM(pf.Page_Views * d.Percentage) as Page_Views
FROM PageFacts pf
JOIN Device_Pct d on d.PageSurkey = pf.PageSurkey
GROUP BY pf.Date, pf.Url_Id, d.Device_Id;
```

This seems like the way to go (since adding in new dimensions which further slice the data only requires knowing the ratio to split by), but I don't know if there's a better practice. Any insight would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding a nullable column to a table is a metadata-only change when you use `ONLINE`, no rebuild at all. DW experts always say to de-normalize (I personally feel that's wrong, but that's a theological argument) so if you are committed to DW concepts, you won't put this in a separate table

Comment: This approach will also fail if you need to add more and more dimensions later, since you'll have bunch of joins with percentages of percentages (which you'll need to calculate in some way before) that will slow down your data mart. If you have some EDW layer, you can rebuild your data mart from some point in time (think, no one will analyze 30 y/o data with this new granularity). If you have only data marts after staging, you can use this new granularity from now since there was no info before, but you've already verified that data earlier.

Comment: If you have a "star" schema on which the OLAP cube is spinning, then you will have no choice but to rebuild the fact table with a new dimension (Device_Id). Otherwise, any "crutch" is bad practice, and any additional JOIN increases the time for data retrieval in the future, this is critical for ROLAP. This is my opinion. Well, for the future, plan in advance the architecture of the solution with all the necessary dimensions and scalability of the solution.

Comment: @Charlieface I see. yea I didn't consider the denormalization aspect.

Comment: @dzhukov good call, yea additional joins wouldn't be good practice here, I see that now.

Comment: This is the reason why you should always build your initial fact tables at the lowest possible grain. You can then create aggregates off them with very little effort as/when you need them. If you start off with an aggregated fact table then you run into the problems you are now facing

Comment: @NickW - Is it always possible to design DW at the lowest grain, without considering the reporting requirements, and just seeing the OLTP? I believe, there will be lot of transactional entities in OLTP, so a lot of facts in DW?

Comment: I meant the lowest grain relevant to your reporting requirements e.g. if the requirement is to have a monthly count but you have the data available to build a daily count then it is good practice to build the daily first and then the monthly on top of it. This gives you flexibility e.g. if there is subsequent requirement for a weekly count you can generate it easily; if you only had the monthly count you would have to start from scratch to create a weekly count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you will rebuild the fact table if you change its grain.  That's a pretty significant design change to the dimensional model, and I don't see any benefit to complicating the schema to avoid rebuilding the fact table.

If you want, you could introduce this as an *additional* fact table, but it wouldn't have "percentages" just a normal fact table:

```
CREATE TABLE PageDeviceFacts 
(
    Date DATE references DimDate,
    Url_Id INT references DimUrl,
    Device_ID INT references DimDevice,
    Page_Views INT,
    constraint pk_PageDeviceFacts
      primary key (Date,Url_Id,Device_ID)
);
```

And if it's a big table, make the PK non-clustered and create a clustered columnstore index

```
create clustered columnstore index cci_PageDeviceFacts on PageDeviceFacts
```

And the old PageFacts table becomes an aggregate fact in the model.

Comment: Ah, ok yea that makes sense. Using a clustered columnstore index is useful too, I didn't think about that.